# javascript - get custom attribute based on an id

Tags: javascript, html, css, attributes, htmlelements

How can I find the seq number given the id in this example?

```
<table>
<tr class="row_header thin_border"> 
    </tr><tr id="id33192010101533333"  seq="2">
    <td>20101015</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>730</td>        
    <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteActivity(3319,20101015,1);">Click</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick='selectEditActivity("id3319201010153333");'>Click</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="id3319201010151111"  seq="3">
    <td>20101015</td>
    <td>600</td>
    <td>730</td>        
    <td><a href="#" onclick="deleteActivity(3319,20101015,1);"> <img src="/bbhtml/img/deleteAction.png"></a></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick='selectEditActivity("id3319201010151111");'><img src="/bbhtml/img/editAction.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
<table>


<script>
    function selectEditActivity(pass_id){
        alert("seq# =:" + ???)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

try this

```
var id = document.getElementById("divId").getAttribute("attributeId");
```

Comment: Might add that you can now use "data-seq" as a Valid custom attribute in HTML 5

Answer (score 9):

## How to get an attribute based on an id

With jQuery :

```
var seq = $('#id33192010101533333').attr("seq");
```

Without jQuery :

```
vvar seq = document.getElementById("id3319201010151111").getAttribute("seq");
```

You can try both of them at [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/awv7c8k9/3/).

Both options should **work in any browser**!

---

## What you really want

First of all, it's better to name your custom attribute `data-seq` instead of `seq`. The HTML5 standard allows custom elements but only considers them valid when their name starts with `data-`.

Also, it's not a good idea to put your click handlers directly in your CSS. It's better to use the `class` property or some custom `data-action` property with a value like `edit` or `delete` and then attach an event handler when you finish loading your page. Then, look at the first ancestor that has a `data-seq` property and get that property.

As one demo says more than a thousand words, here's a demo :

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="delete"]');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        alert('delete ' + e.target.closest('[data-seq]').getAttribute('data-seq'));
    });
}

var list = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="edit"]');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    list[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        alert('edit ' + e.target.closest('[data-seq]').getAttribute('data-seq'));
    });
}
```

```css
table, td {
    border : 1px solid #333;
}

td {
    padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="row_header thin_border"></tr>
    <tr id="id33192010101533333" data-seq="2">
        <td>20101015</td>
        <td>600</td>
        <td>730</td>        
        <td><a href="#" data-action="delete">Click</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-action='edit'>Click</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="id3319201010151111" data-seq="3">
        <td>20101015</td>
        <td>600</td>
        <td>730</td>        
        <td><a href="#" data-action="delete"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRsBv.png?s=64&g=1"></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-action='edit'><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRsBv.png?s=64&g=1"></a></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Or, if you prefer the jQuery way, you can replace the JavaScript code with the following (much simpler) code :

```
$('[data-action="delete"]').click(function(e){
    alert('delete ' + $(this).closest('[data-seq]').data('seq'));
});

$('[data-action="edit"]').click(function(e){
    alert('edit ' + $(this).closest('[data-seq]').data('seq'));
});
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/awv7c8k9/11/) and [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/awv7c8k9/12/) for the same demo on JSFiddle, respectively without and with jQuery.

Answer (score 8):

Retrieve the DOM element and then get the `seq` attribute:

```
document.getElementById(id).getAttribute('seq'); // note: this will return a string, and getElementById might return null in case there is no element with the given id.
```

Comment: I am very close....  // this works
  alert(pass_id)
  // this works;
  var A = document.getElementById("id33192010101533333").getAttribute("seq");
  alert(A);
  // but does not when I use the variable
  var B = document.getElementById(pass_id).getAttribute("seq");
  alert(B);You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [objRef.getAttribute('seq')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute) or plan old dot notation `objRef.seq`

Comment: Property access like `objRef.seq` won't work for custom attributes since the HTML DOM has no mapping between them. (Except in IE<8 due to bugs.) This is the only time using `getAttribute` in an HTML document is actually the right thing. Although one could argue that custom attributes in general aren't the right thing.

Comment: @bobince Back it up with a jsbin and I will give you a cookie. I am not sure where you got that info from.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ojiyu4/2 — bof/undefined in all browsers except IE<9 (I lied about IE8! it's 9 where this is finally fixed) due to the aforementioned bug: IE doesn't understand the difference between attributes and properties, causing a wide-variety of well-known problems. In general DOM properties are a different thing to attributes and should not be confused: consider for example the difference between the `value` attribute (input default value) and the `value` property (current value).

Comment: @bobince did you ever get your cookie?