# Get the value of <a> href using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `<a>` href attribute

```
<a id="cancel" value="<?php echo $subID;?>" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

and I need to get its value (`$subID`) and assign it to a JavaScript variable. How can I do that?

Comment: `$('#cancel').attr('value');` Use `data-value` attribute instead and then `$('#cancel').data('value');`

Comment: `var x = $("#cancel").attr("value")` ?

Comment: Anchors don't have value attributes. The HTML is invalid.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [javascript - get custom attribute based on an id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943652/javascript-get-custom-attribute-based-on-an-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using value, you should use `data-value="<?php echo $subID;?>"`

then you can get the value like this

```
var myVal = $('#cancel').data("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the value as a custom data-attribute

**HTML:**

```
<a id="cancel" data-value="<?php echo $subID;?>" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

And then retrieve the value like this

**JS:**

```
$('#cancel').data('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery. Plain JavaScript is easy enough:

Traditional:

```js
var value = document.getElementById('cancel').getAttribute('value');
console.log(value);
```

```html
<a id="cancel" value="Hello world!" href="#">Cancel</a>
```

Using a CSS selector:

```
var value = document.querySelector('#cancel').getAttribute('value');
```

Using jQuery

```
var value = $('#cancel').attr('value');
```

Although this works (at least in Chrome), a link doesn't have a value attribute so this HTML is invalid. If you use HTML5 (which you probably will), you can make it valid by naming the attribute 'data-value'. Attributes with the 'data-' prefix are allowed for this purpose.

There are other solutions too, but since they are out of scope here, please check [Can I add custom attributes to HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735230/can-i-add-custom-attribute-to-html-tag).

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways (and more) to solve this

With jQuery:

```
var x= $('#cancel').val();
```

with JavaScript:

```
var x= document.getElementById("cancel").value;
```