# How to access data-attributes of HTML elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a dropdown menu in my form. Each option has 3 data-attributes associated with it. When one option is selected I call a function that sets the values of hidden html objects to the value of each data attribute so I can pull that information on the next page. However, the value of the data-attributes keeps coming up as "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

```
 <script>
     function change_charge(x)
     {
     alert (x.dataset.amount); 
     }
 </script>

 <select name="description"  id="description" onchange="change_charge(this)">
     <option value="Test" data-amount="10.00" data-type="charge" >TEST      </option>
  </select>
```

I expect the alert to say the value of data-amount but instead it says "undefined"

I have also tried: 
    alert (x.getAttribute('data-amount'));

But that returns "null".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943677/10957435) shows how you can get a custom attribute from JavaScript.

Summary: you can use `getAttribute()`

```
x.getAttribute("data-amount");
```

**EDIT:**@James also makes a good point, which is x is the selector, not the option. Thus you will probably need a combination of our two answers:

```
x.options[x.selecetdIndex].getAttribute("data-amount");
```

Answer (score 5):

x is the `<select>`, not the `<option>`.  The select has no data- attributes.

If you want the option, use

```
var option = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
console.log(option.dataset.amount);
```